# Missing Microsoft XML schema mystery

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, ms-office

I downloaded the XML schema's for Office 2003 from Microsoft's download site [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe118952-3547-420a-a412-00a2662442d9&displaylang=en) so I can validate Excel documents that people upload to our app. Turns out that they don't work. I receive errors where it can't resolve the type like this:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'udcxf:File' 
to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
```

I've traced this error to the fact that the udc.xsd file which makes a namespace reference to http://schemas.microsoft.com/data/udc/xmlfile which is not valid. When you pull that url up there is nothing served up, so it makes sense that the XML validator is unable to resolve these references.

My question is did Microsoft change the location of their schemas? If so where are they now? Is this format dead?

**[edit]**

It seems all of the referenced URI's that their office 2003 xsd's point to, that are on the host schemas.microsoft.com all just yield 404s.

Comment: You might consider asking Microsoft...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, there is a patent issue and they removed the xml office format for the moment.

Comment: If you're referring to the i4i case, I believe they are only suing a specific feature of Word 2007 (not 2003).

Comment: No, just read an article on this. It's 2003 and 2007, and they lost the suit (and are appealing).

Comment: Wow so that is why they took down their xsd's...sucks for me!

Comment: SLaks is right, it's a Word feature. It doesn't affect their entire XML-based format approach. See my post here for some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904238/have-you-ever-burned-your-hands-by-some-new-and-immature-technology/2018614#2018614

Comment: Ahmad, actually it seems also to apply to Word 2003 (even stated in your quoted articles).  The whole Office XML is good for a makeover IMHO, but I'm no MS insider...