# microsoft office xml format schema references

Tags: xml, html, ms-office, openxml

I am working on a [Google docs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIMBEBYwAA&url=http://docs.google.com/&ei=s43QT5irMc6j-gbV_6z_Cw&usg=AFQjCNHj75Au5kt8svXmuNkhBD_DjnPhNQ&sig2=XV_xnlShzAb9dfnUtx521g) like project so I will convert the pptx,xlsx and docx files formats to html5 files.

Now I understand how to unzip the files and open each folder and I know the role of each file. but I need the xml schema of the document.xml file, what each tag and each attribute means.

I have this [xml spreadsheet reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_xmlss_b) from msdn but I need the similar links and descriptions for office 2007 and 2010 for excel,word and powerpoint.

also I have the full schema of the pptx format [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh643138%28v=office.12%29) but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a link farm or search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549). A question about where to find the schema is off-topic here; a question about how to use it when you find it would be fine. I'd suggest the Microsoft web site; the schema is published, IIRC, and so should be available there. (Also, this [SQ question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053807/missing-microsoft-xml-schema-mystery) might be meaningful as well.

Comment: this is my question I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh643138(v=office.12) and I didn't understand how to use it I need a better one or an explanation.

Comment: There's not a "better one". The Office reference is the Office reference. If you have **specific** questions about how to do things, please ask them (one question per post, as StackOverflow is designed to work). This is not an answerable question in it's current form.